# Export a table containing an XML data column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, export

I need to export a table from SQL Server 2008 from database and then have that table restored on a local database. The issue is that one of the columns contains XML data. What would be the most effective way to do this?

Comment: How would you do this if you did not have a XML column?

Comment: usually, I would export to a flat file. But that causes an error with the XML column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try the "Export Data" wizard. That should work well given your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML instead of flat file.

Sample structure and data:

```
create table XMLTable
(
  ID int,
  XMLData xml
)

insert into XMLTable values
(1, '<root>item1</root>'),
(2, '<root>item2</root>')
```

Query data using `for xml auto`:

```
select *
from XMLTable
for xml auto, elements
```

Result:

```
<XMLTable>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <XMLData>
    <root>item1</root>
  </XMLData>
</XMLTable>
<XMLTable>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <XMLData>
    <root>item2</root>
  </XMLData>
</XMLTable>
```

Load the XML to a XML data type variable in the target DB and use XQuery to insert data. Use `.value()` for regular columns and `.query()` for the XML column.

```
declare @XML xml

set @XML = 
'<XMLTable>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <XMLData>
    <root>item1</root>
  </XMLData>
</XMLTable>
<XMLTable>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <XMLData>
    <root>item2</root>
  </XMLData>
</XMLTable>'

insert into XMLTable(ID, XMLData)
select T.N.value('ID[1]', 'int'),
       T.N.query('XMLData/*')
from @XML.nodes('/XMLTable') as T(N)
```